# How can I profile mypy?

Tags: python, profiling, mypy

Mypy is taking an unreasonably long time to type check my small project. How can I profile it to find out where it's spending all its time? I tried `mypy -v`, which gives a bit more of an idea, but there aren't timestamps on the logs so it's not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did the following:

The `mypy` script calls `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mypy/__main__.py`.

Copy the contents of that into a new file `run_mypy.py`, then edit it to include the following:

```py
...

def console_entry() -> None:
    try:
        import cProfile
        with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
            main(args=["src", "tests", "--no-fast-exit"])
        pr.dump_stats("mypy.prof")
        ...
```

Run with `python -m run_mypy`.

Now you can see how long things took with a profiler like [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/).